# Making a progress bar change a UILabel?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am attemping to try and make a progress bar change a UILabel every .15 of the progress bar to a different phrase could anyone help me out with this?

I have tried using "if" statements i.e `if prog.progress = .15 UIlable.text = @"Fire!"` but everytime I do a higher progress number it just replaces the UILabel with that text.

Does anyone know an easier method for doing this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like a lookup of a string based on the progress. There are lots of ways to do this, simplest maybe to understand is a if/then/else tree.

```
if (prog.progress < .15)
  label.text = @"msg1";
else if (prog.progress >= .15*1 && prog.progress < .15*2)
  label.text = @"msg2";
else if (prog.progress >= .15*2 && prog.progress < .15*3)
  label.text = @"msg3";
```

Warning, didn't compile above code, but something along those lines should work.

Answer (score 0):

DavidNeiss is correct. Make sure you are using == and not =. = is the assignment operator and == is used to test. Also, checking if a value is exactly .15 probably isn't that realistic if it is continuously raising and your program might skip that catch. you should be using < and > to say if it is this range, then do this. If it is in this range, do this.